# How to Display or Print Contents of Environment in R

Tags: r

I hope this question is not a duplicate, because I searched it didn't find any answer(If its a dupe, please let me know I shall remove it).

I am trying to print/display the contents of an environment, but I am unable to do it.

```
library(rlang)
e1 <- env(a = 1:10, b= letters[1:5])
```

When I use `print`, It just give me memory address not the contents(names and values) of that environment.

```
 > print(e1)
<environment: 0x00000000211fbae8>
```

**Note**: I can see the env. contents in R studio Environments tab, I am using **R version**: "R version 3.4.2" and **rlang**:  rlang_0.2.0

**My question is** : What is the right function to print contents of an environment, Sorry the question may be naive, but I am unable to figure out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `ls(e1)` gives `#[1] "a" "b"` do you need values of `a` and `b` as well ?

Comment: @RonakShah, Yes I do need to display it with values, also `names(e1)` work similar to `ls`, but I want to see the values as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `get` with `envir` parameter to get values out of specific environment

```
sapply(ls(e1), function(x) get(x, envir = e1))

#$a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

where

```
ls(e1) # gives
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Great , Thank  You, but it seems there is no direct function to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use mget?

Comment: Also, I think as.list might work with environments (can't test right now).

Comment: @Roland actually, it slipped out of my memory. :D

Comment: @Roland That's a good point. Perhaps its better to get it added to answer.

Comment: The main issue is that all answers so far copy all objects from the environment. That's also the case for `as.list`.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mget`

```
mget(ls(e1), envir = e1)
#$a
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 3):

An option can be as:

```
lapply(ls(),function(x)get(x))
```

which prints content of the `global` environment.

```
#Result:

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 1
# 
# [[4]]
# function (snlq) 
# {
#   j <- 1
#   for (i in 1:length(snlq)) {
#     ind <- index(snlq[[i]])
#     if (identical(ind[length(ind)], "2018-05-04") == FALSE) {
#       ss[j] <- i
#       j <- j + 1
#     }
#   }
#   return(ss)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000000001fa07290>
#
#... so on
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its printing the environment reference.

Comment: @PKumar As you can see in my edited output. It had printed content of list, a function and values of many more vectors.

Comment: its printing `[[1]]
<environment: 0x00000000211fbae8>` in my case, its not the desired result, it should print a and b with their values, you can see the example I have given, again thanks for your kind effort, much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
as.list(e1)

# $a
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $b
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

str(as.list(e1))

# List of 2
#  $ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ b: chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```